# Maven shade plugin relocate and bundle not working

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin, maven-dependency

In my POM.xml, I have used maven-shade plugin and relocated the httpClient dependency. But when I print the dependency tree using mvn dependency:tree, I still see the httpClient library in the tree as shown below. Why is this happening. Any help will be appreciated.

```
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.5:provided
```

My POM.xml is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <artifactId>parser</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <!-- change these to the appropriate values -->
  <name>Parser Apps</name>
  <description>Applications to showcase different parsers</description>

  <properties>
<!-- change this if you desire to use a different version of Apex Core -->
<apex.version>3.4.0</apex.version>
    <apex.apppackage.classpath>lib/*.jar</apex.apppackage.classpath>
   <malhar.version>3.4.0</malhar.version>
 </properties>

  <build>
<plugins>
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.9</version>
     <configuration>
       <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.3</version>
     <configuration>
       <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
       <source>1.7</source>
       <target>1.7</target>
       <debug>true</debug>
       <optimize>false</optimize>
       <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
       <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.8</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>copy-dependencies</id>
         <phase>prepare-package</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <outputDirectory>target/deps</outputDirectory>
           <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactSet>
            <includes>
              <include>org.apache.httpcomponents.*</include>
            </includes>
          </artifactSet>
          <relocations>
            <relocation>
              <pattern>org.apache.httpcomponents</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>org.shaded.httpcomponents</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
          </relocations>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
   <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>app-package-assembly</id>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>single</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-apexapp</finalName>
           <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
           <descriptors>
             <descriptor>src/assemble/appPackage.xml</descriptor>
           </descriptors>
           <archiverConfig>
             <defaultDirectoryMode>0755</defaultDirectoryMode>
           </archiverConfig>
           <archive>
             <manifestEntries>
               <Class-Path>${apex.apppackage.classpath}</Class-Path>
               <DT-Engine-Version>${apex.version}</DT-Engine-Version>
               <DT-App-Package-Group-Id>${project.groupId}</DT-App-Package-Group-Id>
               <DT-App-Package-Name>${project.artifactId}</DT-App-Package-Name>
               <DT-App-Package-Version>${project.version}</DT-App-Package-Version>
               <DT-App-Package-Display-Name>${project.name}</DT-App-Package-Display-Name>
               <DT-App-Package-Description>${project.description}</DT-App-Package-Description>
             </manifestEntries>
           </archive>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>

   <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.7</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <configuration>
           <target>
             <move file="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-apexapp.jar"
                   tofile="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.apa" />
           </target>
         </configuration>
         <goals>
           <goal>run</goal>
         </goals>
       </execution>
       <execution>
         <!-- create resource directory for xml javadoc-->
         <id>createJavadocDirectory</id>
         <phase>generate-resources</phase>
         <configuration>
           <tasks>
             <delete dir="${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/xml-javadoc"/>
             <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/xml-javadoc"/>
           </tasks>
         </configuration>
         <goals>
           <goal>run</goal>
         </goals>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>

   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.9.1</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>attach-artifacts</id>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <artifacts>
             <artifact>
               <file>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.apa</file>
               <type>apa</type>
             </artifact>
           </artifacts>
           <skipAttach>false</skipAttach>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>

  <!-- generate javdoc -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <!-- generate xml javadoc -->
      <execution>
        <id>xml-doclet</id>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>javadoc</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <doclet>com.github.markusbernhardt.xmldoclet.XmlDoclet</doclet>
          <additionalparam>-d ${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/xml-javadoc -filename ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-javadoc.xml</additionalparam>
          <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
          <docletArtifact>
            <groupId>com.github.markusbernhardt</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-doclet</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
          </docletArtifact>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <!-- Transform xml javadoc to stripped down version containing only class/interface comments and tags-->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>transform-xmljavadoc</id>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>transform</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <transformationSets>
        <transformationSet>
          <dir>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/xml-javadoc</dir>
          <includes>
            <include>${pmalhar.versioroject.artifactId}-${project.version}-javadoc.xml</include>
          </includes>
          <stylesheet>XmlJavadocCommentsExtractor.xsl</stylesheet>
          <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/xml-javadoc</outputDir>
        </transformationSet>
      </transformationSets>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <!-- copy xml javadoc to class jar -->
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/xml-javadoc</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-javadoc.xml</include>
              </includes>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

</plugins>

 </build>

  <dependencies>
<!-- add your dependencies here -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.apex</groupId>
  <artifactId>malhar-library</artifactId>
  <version>${malhar.version}</version>
  <!--
       If you know that your application does not need transitive dependencies pulled in by malhar-library,
       uncomment the following to reduce the size of your app package.
  -->
  <!--
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>*</groupId>
      <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
  -->
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.apex</groupId>
  <artifactId>malhar-contrib</artifactId>
  <version>${malhar.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
  <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.apex</groupId>
  <artifactId>apex-common</artifactId>
  <version>${apex.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.10</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.apex</groupId>
  <artifactId>apex-engine</artifactId>
  <version>${apex.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things -

1. You should be aware what relocation does is not "...relocated the httpClient dependency" but as the [source](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) suggests -

   > If the uber JAR is reused as a dependency of some other project,
   >   directly including classes from the artifact's dependencies in the
   >   uber JAR can cause class loading conflicts due to duplicate classes on
   >   the class path. To address this issue, one can relocate the classes
   >   which get included in the shaded artifact in order to create a private
   >   copy of their bytecode
2. When you execute the `mvn dependency:tree` it would display all the dependencies(direct and transitive) included in your project. Instead, the maven shade plugin

> shade:shade is bound to the package phase and is used to create a
>   shaded jar.

renaming or optimizing the dependencies further. Here goes the details for [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) -

> This plugin provides the capability to package the artifact in an
>   uber-jar, including its dependencies and to shade - i.e. rename - the
>   packages of some of the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The dependency is not removed from original POM, so the behavior of `dependency:tree` is correct.

Shade plugin will also generate a new POM (`dependency-reduced-pom.xml`) wherein shaded dependencies are removed from the `<dependencies>` section. This looks like the one you are after.